# Vue router необязательный фрагмент

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Имеется вот такой роут:

```
{
  path: '/:slug/:num_page?/',
  name: 'ThemesList',
  component: ThemesList
}
```

И он отлично справляется с url типа:

```
http://mysite.com/bla-bla-bla/
http://mysite.com/bla-bla-bla/5/
```

Как можно его исправить, чтобы между slug и num_page можно было вставить /page/ и получить вот такие url:

```
http://mysite.com/bla-bla-bla/
http://mysite.com/bla-bla-bla/page/5/
```

но,url

```
http://mysite.com/bla-bla-bla/page/
```

был некорректным?

Answer (score 1):

Что если добавить второй роут?

```
{
  path: '/:slug/:num_page?/',
  name: 'ThemesList',
  component: ThemesList
},
{
  path: '/:slug/page/:num_page/',
  component: ThemesList
}
```

Или использовать алиас:

```
{
  path: '/:slug/:num_page?/',
  alias: '/:slug/page/:num_page/',
  name: 'ThemesList',
  component: ThemesList
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/:slug/page/:num_page/'
```

Вот так должен выглядеть **path** роута

Comment: В таком случае получается, что при запросе только со slug я буду получать ошибки.